# what causes why $().val() sometimes not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to help my friend with his problem regarding to the code of `$().val();`

For example:

```js
$("#btnClick").click(function(){
var getTxt = $("#txtBox").val();
alert(getTxt);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtBox">
<input type="button" id="btnClick" value="Click">
```

I know that above example is running well. But in his case its not getting the input text from the text box and returning a `"" / blank`. He is using `VS2010, Windows 10 OS and IE10`

Comment: You should share his code instead of yours so we can figure it out what is wrong there because there will be another problem not `$().val();`

Comment: @BharatPatidar got the same syntax of coding.

Comment: If its returning `undefined`, that means element is not yet rendered. If it returns `""` this means, it is rendered and value itself is blank

Comment: The only time I think this would be possible (`alert` giving you blank), given this code, is if `#txtBox` is still blank, or a mismatch between selector and ID, causing the set to be empty thus returning blank.

Comment: @Rajesh even we try to input like `username` it is still returning `""`. I don't know why. we also try `.text() , getElementById().value`

Comment: Did you try on another browser ?

Comment: @Silvinus still setting up for new browser.

Comment: @Silvinus no luck my friend.

Answer (score 3):

In your code most likely the problem is the id,if you have multiple elements on the page with the same id javascript will select only the first one in the dom tree

Comment: I think first of it by causing an conflicting of the ID. but its not.